# flutter firebase google auth login Late error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

https://dev.to/movingmelody/flutter-firebase-google-sign-in-auth-with-splashscreen-using-updated-api-23ad

I tried to use the google auth login code as it is during the splash screen on this site, but I still get a late error

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User _user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeUser();
    _initUser();
  }
  Future initializeUser() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final User? firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await firebaseUser!.reload();
    _user = (await _auth.currentUser)!;
    // get User authentication status here
  }
  _initUser() async {
    if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 2),
            () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        MainScreen(_user)),
                    (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
      );
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1),
              () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          MyHomePage()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Splash Screen"),
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

The contents of MyHomePage() or MainScreen(_user) also typed the site code as it is, but the error is still there. Before gradle upgrade, this code worked normally, but after jdk version up and gradle upgrade, the damn late error does not stop.

This is the error

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Restarted application in 1,320ms.
W/DynamiteModule( 6646): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6646): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6646): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/TetheringManager( 6646): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.gwon.goodman
V/NativeCrypto( 6646): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 294 native methods...
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 6646): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/FirebaseAuth( 6646): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
W/System  ( 6646): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/om.gwon.goodma( 6646): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown building MainScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Pro?>], state: _MainScreenState#c8d34):
LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@21075166' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MainScreen MainScreen:file:///F:/flutter%20project/good_man/lib/main.dart:81:25
```

The code on that site is the code from November 2020, but in the meantime, there was a change in the rules of Timer and google auth...
The error is maintained even if you write the same code that uses Future and checks for null using ![enter image description here][1]

This is not a duplicate of the last late question post. After seeing the advice in that article, I wrote down the same code of the blog where I first wrote this code, but I am still embarrassed that the Late error is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are initializing these variables inside the initUser(), but you will get this error if you are using the variables inside the build() method since initUser() is asynchronous meaning it will take time to get the data from the collection. To solve this you can do:

```
@override
  void initState() {  
    super.initState();
    _initUser().whenComplete((){
      setState(() {});
   });
  }
```

This will rebuild the widget tree with the new values.

Comment: return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Pro(),
      child:MaterialApp(

Comment: Could it be a problem to use a provider like this? I added whenComplete((){ , but the error is the same

Comment: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

Comment: I got this new error, so I tried ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in the manifest. The error is still there. There is definitely something wrong with the provider.

Comment: When I moved the same code to a new project, there was no Late error. It seems that there is a problem with the project itself, not with the provider. I have no choice but to start a new project. thank you very much for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use **Late**, you should use null check operator **'?'**

Just replace

```
Late User _user
```

with

```
User? _user
```

Comment: I replaced it, but I get the same error. LateInitializationError: Field '_instance@640075166' has not been initialized.

Comment: @이성권 try my new answer